# Need to remove line breaks based on a search pattern from a file

Tags: awk

Please help me , I have a file in below format

2021-07-20 00:00:00,136 DEBUG [org.mobicents.ussdgateway.slee.cdr.plain.CDRGeneratorSbb] (SLEE-EventRouterExecutor-50-thread-1) :15:0:4:573103154359::7:0:4:573103800069:Elige el Adelanto de Saldo o Paquete que deseas:

1. Saldo
2. Paq Datos
3. Paq Facebook
4. Paq Minutos
5. Mas
   :1:1:573103154359:1:6:732101609331754:1:1:573218067417:::::FAILED_DIALOG_USER_ABORT:PUSH:2021-07-20 00:00:00.136:397050:4278518086:43063:1,0,4:97493489-a041-44f0-8fc4-fe890b675697

2021-07-20 00:00:00,322 DEBUG [org.mobicents.ussdgateway.slee.cdr.plain.CDRGeneratorSbb] (SLEE-EventRouterExecutor-9-thread-1) :15:0:4:573103154359::7:0:4:573103600003:Elige el Adelanto de Saldo o Paquete que deseas:

1. Saldo
2. Paq Datos

I need to remove the line beaks and need to make it like this

2021-07-20 00:00:00,136 DEBUG [org.mobicents.ussdgateway.slee.cdr.plain.CDRGeneratorSbb] (SLEE-EventRouterExecutor-50-thread-1) :15:0:4:573103154359::7:0:4:573103800069:Elige el Adelanto de Saldo o Paquete que deseas: 1. Saldo 2. Paq Datos 3. Paq Facebook 4. Paq Minutos 9. Mas
:1:1:573103154359:1:6:732101609331754:1:1:573218067417:::::FAILED_DIALOG_USER_ABORT:PUSH:2021-07-20 00:00:00.136:397050:4278518086:43063:1,0,4:97493489-a041-44f0-8fc4-fe890b675697

2021-07-20 00:00:00,322 DEBUG [org.mobicents.ussdgateway.slee.cdr.plain.CDRGeneratorSbb] (SLEE-EventRouterExecutor-9-thread-1) :15:0:4:573103154359::7:0:4:573103600003:Elige el Adelanto de Saldo o Paquete que deseas: 1. Saldo 2. Paq Datos

Have been trying awk utility but without success so far

Best Regards,

Comment: Hello, welcome on SO. Please take the [asking tour](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and learn how to [properly format your questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) such that they are readable.

Comment: While editing your question treat your file content as `Code Sample` for better readability, and share your awk attempt please.

Comment: awk -F \| '{c+=NF}c<3{ORS=""}c>=3{ORS=RS;c=0}1'

Comment: Don't add code or anything else in comments where it can't be formatted and could be missed. [edit] your question to contain all relevant information and see the first 2 comments for how to format your code and sample input/output.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like this might be what you want:

```
awk '
{
    printf "%s%s", (/^[0-9]{4}(-[0-9]{2}){2} [0-9]{2}(:[0-9]{2}),[0-9]{3} DEBUG/ ? ors : ofs), $0
    ors = ORS
    ofs = OFS
}
END { printf ors }
' file
```

but it's an untested guess since we can't copy/paste the example in your question to test with and it isn't formatted legibly.